# Adjust position in the dropdown selection menu

Tags: html, css

I am facing the CSS problem in the dropdown menu selection box. My position in the dropdown box view position is not good. My client is not satisfied look like this view dropdown box. Hope someone can guide me how to solve it. Thanks.

Below is my coding:

```html
<style>
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 70px;
  z-index: 9;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block; /* Change display from block to inline-block */
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover #dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>


<div class="topnav">
<span id="curTime" class='hide'>&nbsp;</span>
<div class="dropdown">
<a id="dropbtn" style="margin-right:20px;" href="#" onclick="setting()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Setting" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-metis-1 btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Tetapan Umum</a>
<a href="#">Pengurusan Pengguna</a>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Edit 1: Move logout button out of dropdown menu -->
<a href="#" onclick="logout()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Logout" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-metis-1 btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

My output show me like the below picture:

[image: Output 1]

I expected the result is like below the picture:

[image: Output 2]

Comment: adding `width: fit-content;` to dropdown-content will make the text entirely visible, and adding something like `padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;` to the anchor's inside it will put a small whitespace inbetween the text and border, i think it will start to look better towords the design

Comment: @RamondeVries Thanks for your answer. Can you write down in below the comment answer using my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've added some padding to the anchor's inside the `dropdown-content` div and on the div itself i've added `width: fit-content` to make sure it will not cutoff the text inside.

```html
<style>
.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 70px;
  z-index: 9;
  width: fit-content;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block; /* Change display from block to inline-block */
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover #dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>


<div class="topnav">
<span id="curTime" class='hide'>&nbsp;</span>
<div class="dropdown">
<a id="dropbtn" style="margin-right:20px;" href="#" onclick="setting()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Setting" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-metis-1 btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Tetapan Umum</a>
<a href="#">Pengurusan Pengguna</a>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Edit 1: Move logout button out of dropdown menu -->
<a href="#" onclick="logout()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Logout" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-metis-1 btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
</a>
</div>
```